# CSS Menu Div: Issue w/ Either Background Color & Width, or Clipping, Depending on Where I Place It in the HTML

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, responsive-design, background-color

First, here's the [live page](http://www.juliedaileydesigns.com/FAQs.shtml) I'm working on. Pretty simple & bare-bones but I've run into a snag I can't figure out. Being so minimalistic I didn't like the way the text spread out across larger screens so I contained it to a centered 1024w block where on anything larger than that the empty space on the sides turns black so the content doesn't seem lost in a sea of excess white background on the larger screens. So far so good. Going down from 1024, it resizes fine EXCEPT for a little bit of clipping of the text that occurs on the right side of the screen. On mobile you can pinch to zoom out a little but on computers it creates a scroll bar.

As is, the div that contains the menu buttons (div class="dropdown") is inside the content div (div id="FAQs"). If I move it up out of that div (and change nothing else), simply placing it immediately after body and above FAQs,  the clipping issue goes away and the button positioning doesn't change at all. Great! But that creates a much bigger issue for me of keeping the background color the same as the content FAQs section which I think would entail creating another container/wrapper div for the .dropdown and trying to size it correctly to always match the FAQs content div width regardless of screen size.

So it seems like just figuring out the variable that's causing the clipping with the menu where it is (inside the FAQs) would be the easiest thing but I have been staring at it and tinkering with it for two nights and haven't been able to figure it out yet.

Here's the codes:

```css
body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5; /* OFF WHITE */
  font-size: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

/* for screens 1026px and greater */
@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) { 
body { background-color: #000000; } /* BLACK */
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
      margin-top: 10px;
}

.dropbtn {
    background-color: #6b6b6b; /* GRAY */
    color: #ffffff; /* WHITE TEXT */
    min-width: 175px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 4px solid #0099ff; /* BLUE */
    border-radius: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
      box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #6b6b6b; /* GRAY */
    width: 95%;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border: 4px solid #0099ff; /* BLUE */
    border-radius: 4px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: #ffffff !important; /* WHITE TEXT */
    padding: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #0099ff; /* BLUE */
    }

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #6b6b6b; /* GRAY */
}

#FAQs {
display: block;
position: relative;
width: 1024px;
max-width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
justify-content: center;
background-color: #f5f5f5; /* OFF WHITE */
padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}

/* for screens 1026px and greater */
@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) { 
#FAQs { box-sizing: border-box;
border-left: 2px solid #ff0000; /* RED */
border-right: 2px solid #ff0000;
}
}   

h1 {
font: 15pt Arial;
color: #ff0000; /* RED */
padding: 0px;
}

dt {
font-size: 13pt;
font-weight: bold;
}

dt:first-letter { 
color:#ff0000; /* RED */
font-weight: bold;
}

dd {
font-size: 13pt;
margin: 0;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}

dd:first-letter { 
color:#FF0000; /* RED */
font-weight: bold;
}

a:link {
    color: #0099FF; /* BLUE */
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 13pt;
}

a:visited {
    color: #0099FF; /* BLUE */
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    color: #FF0000; /* RED */
    text-decoration: none;
}

:target,
  .target {
    background-color: #ffff00; /* YELLOW */
    }
```

```html
<body>

<div id="FAQs">

<!-- this menu is actually a SSI include -->
<center>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Button 1 Label</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="URL">Link</a>
      <a href="URL">Link</a>
  </div></div> 
  
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Button 2 Label</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="URL" target="_blank">Link</a>
      <a href="URL" target="_blank">Link</a>
  </div></div>   

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Button 3 Label</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="URL">Link</a>
      <a href="URL">Link</a>
  </div></div>
  </center><p>
  <!-- end of include -->

<h1>Frequently Asked Questions:</h1>     
     
<ul>
<li><a href="#Q1" title="Q1">question text</a></li>
<li><a href="#Q2" title="Q2">question text</a></li>
<li><a href="#Q3" title="Q3">question text</a></li>
</ul>

<h1>Answers:</h1>

<dl>
<dt id="Q1">Q: question text</dt>
<dd>A: answer text<br>
<a href="#top"> - Back to Top</a></dd>

<dt id="Q2">Q: question text</dt>
<dd>A: answer text <br>
<a href="#top"> - Back to Top</a></dd>

<dt id="Q3">Q: question text</dt>
<dd>A: answer text <br>
<a href="#top"> - Back to Top</a></dd>
</dl>   

</div>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Why didn't you give much padding into text elements? Because of that scroll bar hide the texts. Of course there is a way to hide the scroll bar but giving much padding is the better solution.

Comment: I did have left & right padding of 10px which I suspected was the culprit but changing the amount of right padding didn't seem to have any effect. Then late last night after going to bed it _finally_ dawned on me that I wasn't accounting for the extra width of the padding in the 1024. So this morning I added `box-sizing: border-box;` to the FAQs and that fixed it. Whew! I don't understand why moving the menu out of the div eliminated the clipping, unless the padding on the buttons was what was pushing the width past 1024. Anyway, problem solved. Thank you for your response.